# SQL statement for maximum common element in a set

Tags: sql, max

I have a table like

```
id contact value
1  A       2
2  A       3
3  B       2
4  B       3
5  B       4
6  C       2
```

Now I would like to get the **common** maximum value for a given set of contacts.
For example: 
if my contact set was {A,B} it would return 3; 
for the set {A,C} it would return 2
for the set {B} it would return 4

What SQL statement(s) can do this?

Comment: I'm guessing what OP is really looking for is maximum **common** value for a given set. {A,B} is 3 because max value for A is 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  SELECT value, count(distinct contact) as cnt
    FROM my_table
   WHERE contact IN ('A', 'C')
   GROUP BY value
   HAVING cnt = 2
   ORDER BY value DESC
   LIMIT 1
```

This is MySQL syntax, may differ for your database. The number (2) in `HAVING` clause is the number of elements in set.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT max(value) FROM table WHERE contact IN ('A', 'C')
```

Edit:  max common

```
declare @contacts table ( contact nchar(10) )


insert into @contacts values ('a')
insert into @contacts values ('b')


select MAX(value)
from MyTable
where (select COUNT(*) from @contacts) = 
      (select COUNT(*) 
       from MyTable t
       join @contacts c on c.contact = t.contact
       where t.value = MyTable.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most will tell you to use:

```
  SELECT MAX(t.value)
    FROM TABLE t
   WHERE t.contact IN ('A', 'C')
GROUP BY t.value
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.*) = 2
```

Couple of caveats:

- The `DISTINCT` is key, otherwise you could have two rows of t.contact = 'A'.
- The number of `COUNT(DISTINCT t.*)` has to equal the number of values specified in the `IN` clause

My preference is to use JOINs:

```
  SELECT MAX(t.value)
    FROM TABLE t
    JOIN TABLE t2 ON t2.value = t.value AND t2.contact = 'C'
   WHERE t.contact = 'A'
```

The downside to this is that you have to do a self join (join to the same table) for every criteria (contact value in this case).